# In Ionic 5, How to display firestore document to the ionic(html) screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have retrieved document from firestore but i don't know how to display that array on the ionic screen. I have tried below code.

**detail.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/data/firestore.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../../credentials';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public firestoreService: FirestoreService, ) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: member-ordering
  detail: any;


  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async showData() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const docRef = db.collection('srv').doc('Selected Items');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      const details = doc.data();

      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        this.detail = details;
        console.log('document2', this.detail);

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log('No such document!');
    }
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting document:', error);
    });
  }


}
```

I got below array. its fine no problem.
[image]

**detail.page.html**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>detail</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-label><h1>Order page</h1></ion-label><ion-button (click)="showData()">check</ion-button><br><br>

 <ion-list><ion-item *ngFor="let da of detail['n']">
 <p>{{da.name}}</p>

 </ion-item></ion-list>


</ion-content>
```

But, it didn't show anything on Ionic screen and getting below error

[image]

welcome, if anyone can give the solution for it.

Comment: First you need to set the retrieved data in detail variable, and inside if doc.exists under const detail = doc.data(); add here this.detail = detail;

Comment: I tried as you said "this.detail = detail;" but it showed this error    "Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot set property 'detail' of undefined"

Comment: docRef.get().then((doc) => {... this.detail = detail as any;...}

Comment: It shows this  "Cannot find name 'detail'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.detail'? "

Comment: No detail is reference of const detail, add it under it.

Comment: docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    const detail = doc.data();

    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        this.detail = detail;
        console.log('document2', this.detail);

    } else ...

Comment: can u see above code! it still getting error.

Comment: Yes because of keyword function, do as i told you replace it with like this: docRef.get().then((doc) => {...

Comment: And error the same , (error) => {...

Comment: docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      const details = doc.data();

      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        this.detail = details;
        console.log('document2', this.detail);

    } else {...

Comment: It shows "ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: for detail: any = []; define it as detail: any; without = [];

Comment: yes, its cleared but another error is that "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Comment: Yes since in html your calling let data of detail, and detail is array of property n, so you need to edit it to let da of detail['n']

Comment: the error displaying continuously "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined"

Comment: Try to console.log(this.detail) and edit you question with the log.

Comment: Now, I have changed this question according to my problem. could you see it?

Comment: Ok now try to log this.detail['n'] and see if it logs the objects inside it.

Comment: Yes, now its working. Thankyou soooo much for your helping lot @Mostafa Harb.

Comment: You're welcome mate <3.

Answer (score 0):

with mr Mostafa Harb helps, I have solved the error.
Here, what i did before is that just changed **detail.page.ts** page. given below

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/data/firestore.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../../credentials';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public firestoreService: FirestoreService, ) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: member-ordering
  detail: any;
  detail1: any;

 


  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async showData() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const docRef = db.collection('srv').doc('Selected Items');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      const details = doc.data();

      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        this.detail = details;
        console.log('document2', this.detail);
        this.detail1 =this.detail['n'];
        console.log('document3', this.detail['n']);

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log('No such document!');
    }
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting document:', error);
    });
  }

}
```

Now, it's working fine for me.